# preprocessor to embed .css files into .html files

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a tool that will embed `link` CSS files into the `.html` file.

This tool would scan the `.html` file. It would replace a line like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
```

with the contents of the file `main.css` (wrapped in a `<style>` element).  It would re-write the `.html` file with the embedded CSS code.

I have found tools that "inline" the CSS within HTML elements (`<div style="...">`). These are intended for email.
However, I want a tool that would embed the linked CSS code in a `<style>` element.

Comment: Reported as _off-topic_.  Asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69554/website-preprocessor-to-embed-css-files-into-html-files